# Stable width div with lot of horizontal image to prepare for a jquery slider

Tags: html, css, image, slider, overflow

Here's what i need to do: i have a one-page layout with three image galleries(but i need to do the code for one only, i'll just copy it for the other two) which are set up as in the image. The 940px area(white one) is the centered layout width and content area, the slider controls are outside it(the whole layout is 1200px centered if you include the grey area) and i display 3 images at a time there.

[image]

The code for this now is(the #horizontalDiv is the #container of the image):

```
<div id="horizontalDiv">

    <h2>My h2</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, perspiciatis, officiis, commodi, quis aut eligendi quaerat recusandae placeat nostrum optio maiores voluptates quas repudiandae atque voluptatibus laboriosam itaque mollitia dignissimos!</p>

    <div id="imgSlider">
        <img src="img/uvaDx.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/sliderCantina1.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/sliderCantina2.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/sliderCantina3.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/sliderCantina1.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/sliderCantina2.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/sliderCantina3.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/uvaSx.png" alt="">
    </div>

</div>
```

And my layout is looking like this right now:

[image]

I already centered the images and i hided the two control arrows for now but the rest is set.

## Basically my problem is

what's the best way to setup the container div for the images to show all the images i have(let's say it's 50) to be ready to insert a jquery plugin(still have to decide which, any suggestiong?) that slides all the images in that div?

I can't do the following:

1) make images display side by side(tried float:left but it's not working, do i need anything else?)

2) make the ones out of the div "disappear" so they're not visible(i'm pretty sure i have to use overflow: hidden but since i can't display images side by side i didn't try yet.

I need the **simpliest possible solution** because i have three images showing in the div at the same time like this in my layout while the others are hidden somehwere horizontally(one for this section and two identical sections with different images below this one) also because i'll need to setup a jquery slider which i'm not too familiar with, so the more complicated the markup the more problems i'll have integrating the slider.

I know this should be pretty simple but with all the NivoSlider-like stuff everyone seems to love big one-image image shows instead of sliding ones, I couldn't find anything that fit my needs.

Comment: For what you are trying to do, you want to have 3 images represent different galleries that hold about 50 images? So it's roughly 17 images per each image on the page, am I understanding this?

Comment: I realize i actually confused it a bit. Let's consider a single gallery and not three. I want to have a layout exactly as in the first picture but on the right of the three images displayed there should be more, hidden, ready to be controlled by a js/jquery slider so they can be slided in and then clicked for a lightbox to open them.

I can't do the part where i add more images and they stay hidden somewhere right and outside of the cointainer div(named #imgSlider in my code).

The images may be 4 like 40 so it's about the numbers but the structure.

Comment: This is a [multiple image carousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html), you should be able to change it for your needs:

Comment: Thanks for the link Pete. I actually know Jcarousel but i found it difficuilt to customize/theme to my needs.

I know it's fairly simple but i'd rather have my own html + css layout and then add in a script or something that slides the images adding some simple js and adding classes or something to the div sliding the images..or something like that.

I may implement JCarousel but first i need a decent working html + css markup because i still can't put more than 3 images on the right of the main 3 ones shown in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the **jQuery Cycle2 plugin**, which will turn any element into a slideshow. Basically, you attach it to a parent element and all of the children will become a slideshow, regardless of what they contain.

In your case, the following should work:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.cycle2.min.js'></script>

<div id="horizontalDiv" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="#imgSlider > img" data-cycle-timeout="0" data-cycle-prev="[ID OF PREVIOUS BUTTON]" data-cycle-next="[ID OF NEXT BUTTON]">
    <h2>My h2</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, perspiciatis, officiis, commodi, quis aut eligendi quaerat recusandae placeat nostrum optio maiores voluptates quas repudiandae atque voluptatibus laboriosam itaque mollitia dignissimos!</p>

    <div id="imgSlider">
        <img src="img/uvaDx.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/sliderCantina1.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/sliderCantina2.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/sliderCantina3.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/sliderCantina1.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/sliderCantina2.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/sliderCantina3.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/uvaSx.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Resources:

- jQuery Cycle2 plugin - http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/
- Numerous demos for jQuery Cycle2: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/